# Operator overloading on class properties

Tags: kotlin, operator-overloading

I have a class called `DateTime` like bellow:

```
class DateTime {

  ...

  var day: Int = 0
    set(value) {
      field = value
      println("value changed!!!")
    }

}
```

Now I need to distinguish whether `day` is changing with `dateTime.day = -1` or `dateTime.day -= 1` so that in first case I don't want to allow operation because `day` cannot be less than **Zero** but in the second case I want to subtract `Month` by one and change the `day` to 30 or 31.

I know that there is operator overloading in **Kotlin** but since the `day` property is an `Int`, I cannot change the behavior. And in this two cases the setter will be called and I cannot detect the operator.

So how can I solve the problem, any workaround?

Comment: I think you need a different API design, for example just forbid negative `day` values, and create a `subtractDays` method for the `-=` behaviour.

Comment: @Thomas yes but it would be perfect if I could handle this with operators instead of functions

Comment: Maybe do it like Python's `datetime` module: create a separate `TimeInterval` class so you can do `DateTime(2020, 04, 20) - TimeInterval(days = 42)`. Very clear and very safe.